# .htaccess not working on codeigniter subdomain & directory install

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to install CI under a directory which is also on a subdomain. So my base url would look like http://subdomain.domain.com/ci/

The following htaccess works fine on root of domain but not on directory, the browser says there is a redirect loop error.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com/ci/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/ci/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I am not very skilled with mod rewrite, any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You need to be a bit more explicit on the results you are hoping for in terms of how you want your url structure to look like. Your use of %{HTTP_HOST} will be the initial problem, as that will ignore the trailing `/ci` which is probably why you are getting a redirect loop

Comment: I would like my base installation of CodeIgniter to be located at: http://subdomain.domain.com/ci/index.php

So my normal controller methods would look like: http://subdomain.domain.com/ci/method/

You mentioned %{HTTP_HOST}, should I remove this completely? or use something else? This htaccess code is not my code, I found it a year ago or more now. Thanks

Comment: But you also want any requests to `subdomain.domain.com` to be forwarded to `subdomain.domain.com/ci`?

Comment: No, subdomain.domain.com will not be used at all, I am writing a small app for a client and this is where he wanted it installed, under this directory. The .htaccess file will be placed inside the directory, not the root of the domain. http://sub.domain.com/ci/.htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your /ci directory your htaccess should be as follows

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # this means if the requested file name doesnt exist 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # this means if the requested directory doesnt exist 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Based on your above comments that should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be working at first look. I am going to test a few things and will mark this as the answer shortly if all goes well. Appreciate it!