# CodeIgniter: How to properly setup htaccess for domain forwarding to a subdirectory of a subdomain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have CodeIgniter setup in a sub-directory of a sub-domain. My htaccess file works for the following: http://subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory/

The working htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/


RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

However this does not work when I point a domain name http://www.mydomainname.org to public_html/subdirectory.

What I'm attempting to achieve is I'd like to use http://www.mydomainname.org/whatever/ to mask http://sub.domain.com/subdirectory/index.php/whatever

Is this possible? Is there anything I can add to my htaccess that will allow me to achieve this?

I attempted to use the htaccess answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384554/htaccess-not-working-on-codeigniter-subdomain-directory-install), but had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want both to work, you'll need to add extra conditions for the hostname, try something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# for subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(?:subdirectory/|)(.*)$ /subdirectory/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I now get a 404 error only when I try to go to: http://www.mydomain.org/whatever/, but this still works if I use http://www.domain.org/index.php/whatever.

Comment: @Ryan hmm, try removing the `?` from the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` line

Comment: I still have a 404 without the ?

Comment: The error was on my end. Had a typo in my domain name. Thank you so much for the help!